# Set DataContract's DataMember attributes during runtime?

Tags: .net, attributes

is it possible to dynamically set the datacontract's datamember attributes during runtime? Basically what I need is to read in serialized instances of a class which contained the DataMemeber attributes on two properties at the time of serialization, but the current 'version' does not longer have them but I need to migrate the old data set in these properties over to the new handling... sooo what I kind of need is to let the datacontract deserializer read the data including these 'old' values, and re-serialize them with the new config (as these properties' data is now stored and handled entirely differently).

Is this possible?

Cheers & thanks.
-Jörg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify types/known types - but not AFAIK member information. `XmlSerializer` is a bit more forgiving here... is there a chance the old types used xml attributes? (rather than data-contract attributes).

The other option is to provide an `IDataContractSurrogate` - but that isn't trivial.

Is there any chance you can decorate the class with the old attributes *and* the attributes (etc) for whatever new mechanism you're employing?

If the data is simple (i.e. only one or two types, in a simple relationship), you could use a **parallel** set of classes to deserialize, then copy the data (property-to-property etc) into the new data structure, and re-serialize. This gets harder as the complexity of the model increases.